# Why isn't the first grid box's input getting deleted but the other boxes do when backspace is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've been trying to create a wordle-game called Octordle for the past few days now, but I encountered an error that I have been trying to fix for the past 30 minutes but I just cannot find the solution. When I click backspace on the grid rows, the letters that have been inputted get deleted successfully and clicking backspace allows the grid box before the corresponding one to have  focus, however, when I try to delete the input from the first grid box, it does not get deleted and the input just stays there. (The first grid box is the first element, that is why focus() will not work, but I have tried many alternatives, none of them worked.)

Here is my some of my code, I will link a sololearn project at the end:

Javascript:

```
case 8:

    event.target.previousElementSibling.focus();
    event.target.lastChild.remove();


if (document.getElementById('amo1') === document.activeElement) {
    event.target.lastChild.remove();
}
```

Some of the HTML:

```
<div oninput = "inputFunc(); checkInput();" tabindex = "1" class = "amot" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 0)" contenteditable = "true" id = "amo1"></div>
    <div oninput = "inputFunc()" tabindex = "2" class = "amot1" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 0)" contenteditable = "true" id = "amo2"></div>
    <div oninput = "inputFunc()" tabindex = "3" class = "amot2" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 0)" contenteditable = "true" id = "amo3"></div>
    <div oninput = "inputFunc()" class = "amot3" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 0)" contenteditable = "true" id = "amo4"></div>
    <div oninput = "inputFunc()" class = "amot4" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 0)" contenteditable = "true" id = "amo5"></div>
    <div oninput = "inputFunc()" class = "amot5" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 0)" contenteditable = "true" id = "amo6"></div>
    <div oninput = "inputFunc()" class = "amot6" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 0)" contenteditable = "true" id = "amo7"></div>
    <div oninput = "inputFunc()" class = "amot7" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 0)" contenteditable = "true" id = "amo8"></div>
```

Please help... thank you in advance.

**FULL CODE:**
**https://code.sololearn.com/WhT8nBXjZnAa**

Answer (score 0):

It's erroring on this line

`event.target.previousElementSibling.focus();`

The console says `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')`.

The first element doesn't have a previous sibling to focus.

Comment: Yea I get that part but I want to know how I can make it so it is actually deleted, I just used that as placeholder code, I've tried `event.target.lastChild.remove();` as well, no matter what I do the first grid box input still remains.

Comment: I removed that `focus` line of code and it worked to delete text from the first box for me.

Comment: Yea it works like that but then the backspace kind of loses its purpose, because what it is doing right now is when backspace is clicked the letter gets removed from the current grid box and then the last grid box is focused. I do not want to remove the focus line of code, is there any way I can solve this problem with the line of code?

Comment: you need to decide what you want to happen for the first box, since `event.target.previousElementSibling` doesn't make sense for the first box. You could run `event.target.lastChild.remove();` BEFORE `event.target.previousElementSibling.focus();`, that's one approach.